# why the combo box displays the objects?

Tags: winforms

I have a combobox which I would like to populate with some info. Below is the code:

```
        cmbSelectProject.Items.Clear();
        cmbSelectProject.ValueMember = "Sid";
        cmbSelectProject.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cmbSelectProject.DataSource = new BindingSource(ApiCaller.LstProjects, null);
```

So, there is a class Project with the existing properties "Sid" and "Name". ApiCaller.LstProjects call returns a list of Projects. So I expect the "Name" to de displayed and "Sid" is used as value..  Instead I see the bunch of Project objects displayed in the dropdown.

What am I doing wrong in here? Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Try something like: `var projects = new BindingList<Project>(ApiCaller.LstProjects); cmbSelectProject.DataSource = new BindingSource(projects, null);`. Otherwise, post the prototype of the Project class and the actual type returned by `ApiCaller.LstProjects`. (You should bind to a concrete type or to the Type definition, e.g., `typeof(List<Project>)`, in case the collection is empty or undefined at that time)

Comment: Btw, why `cmbSelectProject.Items.Clear();`? Did you have something else set as datasource before?

Comment: Jimi, thanks for your help.. will check

Comment: Your current *sequence of assignments* is correct: first `DisplayMember`, then `ValueMember`, then `DataSource`. If there's some sort of problem in setting the datasource, it's caused by the datasource itself or its content, at that time. That's why I asked you if you had another datasource set in the Control. Try to set it to `null` before you assign another. The actual content of the `ApiCaller.LstProjects` at the time this code is run also matters; it also matters *where* this code is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This sequence.

1. Set DataSource property.
2. Set ValueMamber and DisplayMember.
3. Refresh Combo. using Refresh() method.